# How to show slider menu and tabbar menu(footer menu) in same app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to make app which include slider menu as well as tabbar menu (footer menu) facing problem to achieve  both at same time

I am able to code either for slider menu or tabbar but facing difficulty to show both same time

Is there any online solution for that, or any suggestion to implement this in objective-C

right now i have added tabbar on each screen , but i have lots of screen so its not good practice , is there any better way to do this

[image]

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to achieve, could you explain better, possibly with examples and what you have done till now.

Comment: I have updated my question hope this can give clear idea

Answer (score 1):

use interface builder.  embed the viewcontrollers in a tabbar controller and then embed each view controller in a navigation controller

[image]
[image]

hierarchy is:

```
                        ---------- navigationcontroller1---------viewcontroller1
                        -
tabbarcontroller------------------ navigationcontroller2---------viewcontroller2
                        -
                        ---------- navigationcontroller3---------viewcontroller3
```

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand clearly, but if what you want is to have a tab bar in each of the viewcontroller shown after clicking on a menu item (in the slider), then just use whatever way to implement a slider menu (eg [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController)) and each menu voice show in the central section a `UITabBarViewController` with the relative ViewControllers.

I am not sure it is a very intuitive design but if that is what you want... Anyway you should give more information and propose a solution or partial one to help.